# Hovering button doesn't show URL preview - Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I have just started using Gatsby, by using the code below, it won't display the destination URL at the bottom left of the browser when hovering the button. The only way is to wrap the button into a `<Link>` which is not the best choice from an HTML perspective. May you point me to the right direction? Thank you.

```
import { navigate } from "gatsby"

<button onClick={()=>{navigate("/contact/")}} role="link">Contact Now</button>
```

Comment: Buttons by default won't show a browser destination link because they're not anchors. (maybe I misunderstand you?). The usual way is to use CSS to style the `<a>anchor</a>`   to look like a button.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I guess I will proceed with anchors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are triggering a JavaScript function in your `<button>` `onClick` handler, you will never be able to see the destination while hovering the element, because it's unknown until the user clicks it.

I don't know why do you say that `<Link>` "is not the best choice from an HTML perspective" but it is, it will behave as an anchor (`<a>`) in the end keeping all the React routing functionality and of course, displaying the destination URL on hover.